# Download build drop from hosted Team Foundation Service

Tags: continuous-integration, build-automation, continuous-deployment, azure-devops

Using the hosted Team Foundation Service at tfs.visualstudio.com, one has the option in a Build Definition to "Copy build output to the server" which creates a zip of the drop folder that can be downloaded over https via team web access. I really need to download this drop automatically, so I can chain input to the next stage in my build pipeline.

Unfortunately, the drop URL is not obvious, but can be created using the [TfsDropDownloader](https://officesharepointci.codeplex.com/releases/view/102774).

TL;DR - I can't get the TfsDropDownloader to work, I'm hoping someone else has used this tool or a similar method to succesfully download a drop from https://tfs.visualstudio.com

Using the command line TfsDropDownloader.exe I can do this:

```
TfsDropDownloader.exe /c:"https://MYPROJECTNAME.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection" /t:"ProjectName" /b:"BuildDefinitionName" /u:username /p:password
```

...and get an empty zip file with the correct build label name of the last successful build e.g. BuildDefinitionName_20130611.1.zip

Running the source code in the debugger, this is because the URL that is generated for downloading:

```
https://tflonline.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/resources/containers/804/drop/BuildDefinitionName_20130611.1.zip
```

..returns a content type of application/json, which is unsupported. This exception is swallowed by the application, but not before the empty zip file is created.

Is it possible the REST API on Team Foundation Service has changed in some way so the generated URL is no longer correct?

Note that I am using the "alternate credentials" defined on my Team Foundation Service account (i.e. not my live ID) - using anything else gets me TF30063: not authorized.

Answer (score 6):

I got it working by using alternate credentials, but I also had to access the REST API via a different path.

The current [TfsDropDownloader](https://officesharepointci.codeplex.com/releases/view/102774) builds a URL that looks like this:

```
https://project.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/resources/containers/804/drop/BuildDefinitionName_20130611.1.zip
```

This returns empty JSON whenever I try to use it. I'm definitely authenticated, because if I tweak the URL to:

```
https://project.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/resources/containers/804/drop
```

I get a nice JSON listing of every single file in the drop, but no zip.

From spying on the SSL traffic to https://tfs.visualstudio.com with Fiddler I saw that clicking the "Download drop as zip" link I can see that there is another endpoint at:

```
https://project.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/ProjectName/_api/_build/ItemContent?buildUri=vstfs%3a%2f%2f%2fBuild%2fBuild%2f639&path=%2Fdrop
```

...which does give you a zip. The "vstfs%3a%2f%2f%2fBuild%2fBuild%2f639" portion is the URL encoded BuildUri.

So I've changed my version of GetServerPath in the TfsDropDownloader source to do this:

```
private static string GetServerPath(TfsConnection collection, IBuildDetail buildDetail)
{
    var downloadPath = string.Format("{0}{1}/_api/_build/ItemContent?buildUri={2}&path=%2Fdrop",
                                            collection.Uri, 
                                            HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(buildDetail.TeamProject), 
                                            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(buildDetail.Uri.ToString()));

    return downloadPath;
}
```

This works for me for the time being. Hopefully this helps someone else with the same problem!

Comment: It looks like your code was adopted in a later release. However, at this time, it still won't authenticate (at least for me). Is there a newer API or method to accomplish this at this time?

Comment: @Mario Tacke did you use alternate credentials? You set these up from your profile area. Your normal TFS login won't work.

Comment: I did. I tried alternate credentials with both primary and secondary login name and the alternate password. Whenever it tries to authenticate, I get a Windows Security dialog which asks for a password. Upon entering the correct password, the dialog pops up again and a second try results in denial as well... Could that be UAC related?

Comment: I narrowed it down to our company network. If I run the same exact command via my cell network connection it works; on our company network it does not. I appreciate your help @idlemind.

Comment: Well done for figuring it out, I hate those corporate firewalls! Good luck